# Optimizing a recursion code over lists

Tags: python, optimization, recursion

I'm writing three functions which iterate over lists, I want do this recursively, but I think this code is not as efficient as it could be.

```
def flatten(lst):

    if type(lst)==int:
        return [lst]
    elif lst==[]:
        return lst
    else:
        return sum([flatten(sub) for sub in lst], [])

def size(lst): #counts how many numbers and pairs of parentheses in the list
    global cnt
    cnt=0
    if type(lst)==int:
        cnt+=1
        return 1

    if lst==[]:
        cnt+=1
        return 1
    else:
        return (sum([size(sub) for sub in lst])+cnt)

def transform(f, lst):
    if lst==[]:
        return []
    if isinstance(lst,(int,float)):
        return f(lst)
    else:
        return [transform(f,sub) for sub in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

The flatten function will not handle any element other than integer or list. A better and simpler way of handling it is using a predefined function flatten.

```
import compiler.ast as cmp
flatten = cmp.flatten

>>> flatten([1,2,[3,[4]]])
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

Now the size function can be rewritten as :

```
def size(lst):
    return len(lst) + sum(
        nested_count(l) for l in lst if isinstance(l,list))
```

I also noticed that you take care of float in transform function and not in (your) flatten function. Please ensure all cases or add catch Exceptions where you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

### flatten

You could try [@PranavRaj](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42116/pranav-raj)'s suggestion, but that won't work in Python 3, as `compiler` is deprecated.

This would work in Python 3 too ([from this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)):

```
def flatten(lst):
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
```

### size

I don't really understand what you're doing with the global `cnt` variable there. Using global variables is usually a sign of bad design, and in your case you're not actually using it for anything, so you can just drop it.

Here's a simpler and more general implementation:

```
def size(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(lst, basestring):
        return 1 + sum([size(sub) for sub in lst])
    return 1
```

### transform

Here's a simpler and more general implementation:

```
def transform(f, lst):
    if isinstance(lst, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(lst, basestring):
        return [transform(f, el) for el in lst]
    return f(lst)
```

Comment: When I run the function size you wrote I get this error: NameError: global name 'collections' is not defined